# Какой инструмент в PHP можно использовать для декодирования URL?

Tags: php

Понадобилось декодировать в строку из формы, вместо `+` приходит `%2B`, какими инструментами это можно сделать?

Comment: `url_decode()` для этого есть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str='+';
$dec=urlencode($str);
print_r($dec);
$adec=urldecode($dec);
echo '<br>';
print_r($adec);
```